# How do i get PostgreSQL notifications work with python?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, pg-notify

i was trying to follow this example from stackoverflow using pg_notify with python. I am not getting this to work. Nothing happens and python does not receive the notification.

Python 3.85 Using Psycopg2. PostgreSQL 13

[python & postgresql: reliably check for updates in a specific table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648921/python-postgresql-reliably-check-for-updates-in-a-specific-table)

First. I created a python function that listened to the postgreSQL. Then i went to pgadmin and
executed

```
select pg_notify('process', 'update');
```

My python function is below

```
def dblisten(connection):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    print("inside")
    cur.execute("LISTEN process")
    while True:
        print("listening")
        select.select([connection],[],[])
        connection.poll()
        events = []
        while connection.notifies:
            notify = connection.notifies.pop().payload
            print ("Got NOTIFY:", datetime.datetime.now(), notify.pid, notify.channel, notify.payload)
if __name__ == '__main__':  # If it's executed like a script (not imported)
connection = psycopg2.connect(host='host', user='user',
                            password='password')
connection.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
        dblisten(connection)
```

Comment: Please show how you are intialising the connection.

Comment: connection = psycopg2.connect(host='host', user='user',
                            password='password')

        connection.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

Comment: I works for me.  Or at least, something happens when I send the notice.  But what happens is some NameErrors.  Maybe I mis-guessed about what your imports are supposed to be.

Comment: This looks pretty much the same as [the docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-notifications).

Comment: One thing that's bitten me with this before - both sides must be connected to the same database: if the python connection is connected to `db1` then `pg_notify` must be called from within `db1` too.